# Large scale database performance ... MongoDB / NoSQL eval

Tags: sql, .net, mongodb, database-design, nosql

I'm working on a project currently where in production we have 100k rows or so in production.

The existing system which I inherited is having quite a bit of problems dealing with this much data due to the complexity of the application.  This will only be compounded year over year with the about the same frequency.  Give we are already having problems I think I need to start investigating options.

This was written in .NET / MSSQL.  I'm trying to evaluate and determine if using a different database structure like MongoDB or maybe even mixed would help improve this.  For example, if the data was modeled in json it would look something like:

Record

```
 {
    1234: "Harry",
    1233: "Black",
    1234: 5
 }
```

Meta

```
{
    1234: {
        name: "First Name",
        alias: "fname",
        guid: "343-3433-4333",
        initalValue: "Calvin",
        type: 1
    },
    1233:{
        name: "Last Name",
        alias: "lname",
        guid: "343-3433-4333",
        initalValue: "Marshall",
        type: 1
    },
    1233:{
        name: "Age",
        alias: "age",
        guid: "343-3433-4343",
        type: 2,
        listId: 1
    }
}
```

List Meta

```
{
    1:{
        1: "0-20",
        2: "20-30",
        3: "30-50",
        4: "50-60",
        5: "60 and older"
    }
}
```

This is a basic example, there is much more data in the record and more complexity in the meta data portion.  Given this, what type of system would you suggest?

Comment: It has problems dealing with 100K rows? wow that must be one sucky database

Comment: @Sammaye haha agreed ...

Comment: The first question is what are you doing with the data. Queying (well defined, many ways to query the data), storing only, ...

Comment: What **exactly** are the problems you encounter with MSSQL and why do you believe that MongoDB is the solution for them?

Comment: @RomEh good question ... lots of querying with dynamic queries, for example user can defined all different types of filters, sorting, etc via UI ...

Comment: You should do a lot more research into how indexes work in MongoDB before jumping into a new platform. If a reasonably configured and designed MS SQL server can't handle your requirements, I'm skeptical that MongoDB will be better for you. In fact, you may find "dynamic" queries to be particularly troublesome depending on your indexing requirements.

Comment: If you are having problems with 100,000 records then you need to look at tuning the existing database and queries.  Start with one problem query and table design behind it and post it.  100,000 records is not a large scale database.

Comment: Not discussing the actual database, but the way that you are describing the data in Mongo looks terse. It's hard to say since it's just an example, but lists can and should be described using arrays. For example: `{ranges: ["0-20", "20-30", "30-50", "50-60", "60 and older"]}`. Think of documents like maps (`Dictionary` in .NET), and join-able lists as arrays of values/objects. It seems odd to have keys that are integers that look eerily like relational, auto-incremented primary keys in a MongoDB document without a good reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use SQL Server 2012, you can consider ColumnStore Index technology : 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492088.aspx, especially the scenarios : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492088.aspx#Scenarios, and check if it can fit.

This tehcnology will be improved in the new version of SQL Server, SQL Server 2014.

Comment: Would you stay away from mongo despite the document-like design for the record data?

Comment: ColumnStore Index is a kind of document concpet brought to MSSQL. If you already have MSSQL, in the right version, maybe it is a low effort solution for your case. You could improve the performance with no such effort and no new technology to adopt.

Comment: this sounds too good to be true ;) ... whats the release date for 2014?

Comment: There no date for the moment, but probably before june 2014. I have seen some demonstration, some new features were amazing, including ColumnStore Index.